# Change column's data-type in Sqlite using Room Persistence Storage

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I've table `Invoice` as:

```
TABLE Invoice (UserId INTEGER NOT NULL, InvoiceNumber TEXT NOT NULL, Amount REAL NOT NULL, ...)
```

I want to change `UserId` column's data-type to `TEXT` without loosing any data that's already present in the table.

How to do it using `Room` without dropping and re-creating table?

Comment: Please refer: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions

Comment: @GokulNathKP I know about Migrations but in that case also we can not simply change the column's data-type. All we have to do is 'create temporary table with new data-type, copy data from old table, delete old one and rename temporary table'. I'm asking if we could change data-type without all this

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly change data-type of a column (`UserId`). You can follow below steps to solve your issue!

1. Add new column (`UserIdTemp`)
2. Make a copy of existing data from `UserId` to `UserIdTemp` (convert the data to required format)
3. Drop the old column (`UserId`)
4. Create a new column (`UserId`) with new data-type
5. Copy data from `UserIdTemp` to `UserId`
6. Drop `UserIdTemp`

Comment: Unable to drop a column in sqlite, tried "ALTER TABLE collections_temp DROP COLUMN name"